# How to use ellipses in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

In My App, I wanted to retrieve full Name of current user from firebase and wanted to show it  in TextField which is basically placed in App Bar and the half Name display in TextField is end with elipses.
we can use elipses for Text but how can I use for TextField.

here is my code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomeTab> {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  TextEditingController NameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/logo.png",
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: TextField(
                controller: NameController,
                enabled: false,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black),
               // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
void getData() {
    dbRef.child('Users').child(user.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
      setState(() {
        var name = snapshot.value['name'];
        NameController.text = name;
     
      });
    });
  }
}
```

When I use this code getting this error:

**════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#10696 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
TextField**

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to show the name of the user, there's no need to use `TextField`, simply use `Text` Widget.
In this case(`TextField`), wrap `TextField` with `Container` or `SizedBox`, with `height` & `width` properties.